# Checking whether a TimeDelta object is equal to a specific time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a piece of code:

```
df['time'].iloc[1]+df['time'].iloc[2]
```

Which returns:

`Timedelta('0 days 00:04:51')`

And I am trying to write an `if` statement that checks its value:

```
if df['time'] == '0 days 00:04:51':
             print ('True')
else:
          print ('False')
```

It is printing `False`, and I am not sure why.  How do I check values of a Timedelta object?

Comment: The check can be done with `df['time'] == pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:04:51')` but note that you can not use this in an if statement. Because it returns a boolean array not a single True or False. You need to reduce that.

Comment: To compare days: `delta.days <= 0`, will be True if delta is less than or 0 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
if df['time'] == timedelta(days = 0, minutes = 4, seconds = 51):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to solutions presented already, there is yet another way to check the `timedelta` value in Python3:

```
if df['time'].total_seconds() == 291.0:
    print("true")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is you are comparing `timedelta("0 days 00:04:51")` to the string `"0 days 00:04:51"`, when you should instead be comparing it to a similar object, thus:

```
if df['time']==timedelta(0,291):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Note that timedelta:

- has no capital.
- takes 0, 291 as arguments; this means "0 days and 291 seconds".

However, there is a shorter way of doing this, thus:

```
print(str(df['time']==timedelta(0,291)))
```

This has exactly the same result and is a tad more compact.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am receiving an error: `name 'Timedelta` is not defined.  I tried `from datetime import timedelta`, but that didn't seem to solve the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: That fixed that error, but now I am receiving an error `unsupported type for timedelta days component: str`

Comment: sorry; replace it with `timedelta(0,291)`, as 291 seconds = 4:51